# batch command to grab latest file by wildcard name

Tags: batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

I'm trying to take the newest file from a directory that begins with `LEEXTR_DC30` and copy it to another directory. The source file is dated. I would also like to get rid of the date and just save it to the new directory as `LEEXTR_DC30.txt`. I then want to delete the copied file at a specific time.... Any help would be greatly appreciated!! I have a start below...
The original file is named something like this (depending on day it's created) `LEEXTR_DC30_201404180915a_1.txt`

```
copy "\\taaproc0200a\D$\hbc\data\dc\backup\LEEXTR_DC30*.txt" "D:\Kronos\InterfaceDesigner\DA DC Interface\Associate\DCXX Associate Files"
exit /b 0
```

Comment: We need to know the date format on the filename, at least to know how to split the name to remove the date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rem get latest file:
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir "\\taaproc0200a\D$\hbc\data\dc\backup\LEEXTR_DC30*.txt" /s /od /b') do set a=%%i
rem copy it:
copy "%a% "D:\Kronos\InterfaceDesigner\DA DC Interface\Associate\DCXX Associate Files\LEEXTR_DC30.txt"
```

As for "delete the copied file at a specific time" - can you specify this? After x days? On next Monday? If there is a new version?

Last one would be easy: no need to delete, just overwrite it. (`copy`-parameter `/y`)

Comment: Just to be pernickity  - the /s can match an unintended file.  It may be best to either use pushd to change the CWD to the source folder, or use a variable for the source folder and add that to the filename too, removing /s